# Volume of solid region bounded by $z=4x$, $z=x^2$, $y=0$, and $y=3$ as an iterated integral

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

> Suppose R is the solid region bounded by the plane $z = 4x$, the surface $z = x^2$, and the planes $y = 0$ and $y = 3$. Write an iterated integral in the form below to find the volume of the solid R.
>   $$\iiint\limits_Rf(x,y,x)\mathrm{d}V=\int_A^B {\int_C^D {\int_E^F\mathrm{d}z} \mathrm{d}y} \mathrm{d}x$$

I need to find the limits, I found A and C which are zeros and I could not find the rest of the limits

Answer (score 2):

The region in xz plane is described by $0 \le x \le 4$ and $ x^2\le z\le 4x$

Thus the volume is found by  $$V=\int_{0}^4 \int_{0}^{3} \int_{x^2}^{4x}  dzdydx$$

Answer (score 0):

the volume comes out to be:

$$\int_{0}^4 \int_{0}^{3} \int_{x^2}^{4x}  1dzdydx$$